# Trouble undestanding notation $\left\{\sup_n f_n > a \right\} = \cup_n\left\{f_n>a\right\}$

Tags: measure-theory, notation

I am reading a paper on measure and integration where the following notation is used:
$$\left\{\sup_n f_n > a \right\} = \cup_n\left\{f_n>a\right\}$$
$(f_n:(X, \mathcal{A})\longrightarrow \mathbb{R})$
I don't think I understand this notation. The RHS is just a function and the LHS is a union of functions. I don't see why this gives the $\sup_n$. Similarly, the infimum is defined
$$\left\{\inf_n f_n > a \right\} = \cap_n\left\{f_n>a\right\}$$
Can someone help me undestand this?

Comment: Both sides are sets corresponding to pre-images, and not functions. If $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$, then $\{ g>a \}=\{ x\in X: g(x)>a \}$.

Comment: Also, how would you define an intersection of functions? By viewing them as relations?

Answer (score 1):

You have to show appropriate set inclusions, let $x\in X$ such that $\sup_n f_n(x) >a$, show that there exists $n$ such that $x\in  \{ z\in X: f_n(z)>a \}$.

Likewise show that if $x\in X$ where $f_n(x)>a$, then $x\in \{ z\in X: \sup_n f_n(z)>a \}$.